# Almacenar datos numéricos mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, base-de-datos

estoy investigando la forma de trabajar de forma correcta con datos para realizar una comparación.

Tengo una tabla compuesta de la siguiente manera:

CUITS 
0-1-2-3 
4-5-6 
7-8-9

Busco en los cuits de usuarios finalizados en algunas de esas terminaciones y realizo una operación.

Cómo es la forma correcta de guardar en una tabla mysql esos datos para después poder preguntar si cuit-cliente finaliza por ejempo en 5?

Agradezco mucho todo tipo de orientación y por destinar tiempo en mi consulta.

EDITADO: AMPLIACIÓN DE INFORMACIÓN

La imagen a continuación es una tabla que según el CUIT (DNI) de diversas personas se obtiene del mes actual la fecha de vencimiento de un servicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada día se debe buscar en base a la fecha actual la fecha de vencimiento, verificar en cada tipo de cliente (Autónomos - Ganancias y Convenio) y dentro de la fecha encontrar las terminaciones de cuits de los clientes 0-1-2-3 etc. y mandar un mail a los que se encuentren en ese rango.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Si, las comparaciones que vas a hacer son solo strings el campo debería ser varchar, ahora si las comparaciones que deseas hacer es mayor que o menor que en ese caso los campos deberían ser INT, no obstante si tienes los campos definidos como varchar igual puedes convertirlos a números a través de las herramientas que proveen los distintos lenguajes, pero para tomar una buena decisión es necesario analizar bien este tipo de datos, lo que yo veo es que es algo fuera de standard y tiene algún comportamiento un tanto ambiguo si es que lo vas a comparar como numero siendo un string.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta adecuada depende del modelo de datos, del uso que darás a esos valores en diferentes contextos y de pensar en futuras evoluciones de tu aplicación. Por ejemplo: ¿qué representa cada fila en tu ejemplo? ¿cada una de esas filas está relacionada con alguien en el modelo (supongo que al presentar valores agrupados hay *alguien* que los agrupa: un `ID` de otra tabla, una fecha, u otra cosa)? ¿No habría que normalizar en este caso, llevando cada número a una fila y poniéndolo en relación con su agrupador? O sea, imaginemos que `0-1-2-3` pertenecen a `X`...

Comment: ... se podría pensar en *normalizar*  poniendo cada dato en una fila y relacionándolo con `X`, tendríamos entonces cuatro filas: `X->0`, `X->1`, `X->2`, `X->3` ... y si la siguiente fila tiene un agrupador `Y`, lo mismo: `Y->4`, `Y->5`, `Y->6`  y así sucesivamente. ¿Qué ventajas tiene esto? ¡Todas las del mundo!. Para obter el mayor sólo tendrías que usar `MAX()`. Y si por ejemplo necesitamos saber cuántos asociados tiene `X` ..., lo podrías obtener con un `COUNT()` ... y más cosas. Es sólo un ejemplo para ilustrar. Si no explicas el contexto es complicado responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por sus ideas, amplié la información para que se vea más claro. Las comparaciones son con un string. El cuit de un usuario con los valores mencionados 0-1-2-3 etc.